# Change menu item string for VSPackage

Tags: c#, vspackage

I have a C# VSPackage project. It's a tool that helps with some stuff here in our office. It operates via a Tools menu item. I thought of a better name for the menu item, but how do I change it in the code? Every instance I've tried changing doesn't effect it at all. I've even tried changing the Assembly name, but apparently that doesn't work for VSPackages. Any ideas?

Comment: Some code would make this question much easier to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check within the `.vsct` file. An example is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166492.aspx

Comment: Okay, feel stupid. In the .vsct file, there is an entry for `ButtonText`. I thought I had changed it as a test, but must has missed it. Thanks!